# Assigning an int to a bool for ternary operation

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I'm new to c++ and trying to understand how the conditional (ternary) operator works.  I'm familiar with its use in java, but very confused about an example that I've seen in c++

```
int main() 
{
   bool three = 3;
   int x = three ? 3 : 0;
   cout << x << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

First, how can a `bool` data type accept an `int`?  Second, `int x = three`, isn't this an assignment and not a conditional test for `x == 3`?  Or is it saying, "create an `int` called `x` and assign it `3` if `three == 3` else `0`?"

Comment: There is no `bool` accepting an `int`. And I don't think it is very different in Java.

Comment: `bool three = 3`? @juanchopanza

Comment: @free_mind Anything that is equal to zero is `false`; Otherwise - `true`?

Comment: @juanchopanza I did and didn't understand it - hence the question

Comment: @free_mind Oh, I thought you meant in the ternary operator, since that is what your question seems to be about. But it has nothing to do with that, I guess. The title and the code sample fooled me.

Comment: `int x = three ? 3 : 0` is not to be read as `(int x = 3) ? 3 : 0`, but as `int x = (three ? 3 : 0)`,  _i.e._ the ternary expression `three ? 3 : 0` is evaluated (returning 3 if `three` is true and 0 if it is false), then `x` is assigned the result of this expression. In this case, `three` was assigned `true` because it was assigned a non-zero `int` which is implicitly converted.

Comment: Sheesh tons of down votes for doing researching, providing an example of my issue and asking a question.

Comment: Indeed. I don't understand the -4 either. I can see the confusion given your coming from Java. But with Java's odd autoboxing, I think the Java conditional is *far* stranger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bool three = 3;` implicitly *converts* 3 to a `bool`, so `three` will have the value of `true`. (Any non-zero number will convert to `true`, zero converts to `false`.)

Also note that the ternary conditional has higher *precedence* than assignment (in C++ and Java).

So `int x = three ? 3 : 0;` is equivalent to `int x = (three ? 3 : 0);`.

`int x = (three ? 3 : 0);` is therefore equivalent to `int x = (true ? 3 : 0);` which is equivalent to `int x = 3;`

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know about the implicit casting.

Comment: @free_mind - there is no implicit **casting**, but there is implicit **converting**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion, so a cast is **always** explicit. A conversion can be explicit (i.e., done with a cast) or implicit (done by the compiler because the language rules tell it to).